# Combine Azure DevOps AndroidSigning@2 tasks

Tags: android, azure-devops, android-build

I'm using Azure DevOps to build an Android app

I have a pair of tasks to sign both the .apk and .aab outputs

```
- task AndroidSigning@2
  displayName 'Sign APK'
  inputs:
    apkfiles: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/*.apk'
    jarSign: true
    jarsignerKeystoreFile: 'My.Keystore'
    jarsignerKeystorePassword: '$(My.Password)'
    jarsignerKeystoreAlias: 'certAlias'
    jarsignerKeyPassword: '$(My.Password)'
    jarsignerArguments: '-sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256'
    zipalign: true


- task AndroidSigning@2
  displayName 'Sign AAB'
  inputs:
    apkfiles: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/*.aab'
    jarSign: true
    jarsignerKeystoreFile: 'My.Keystore'
    jarsignerKeystorePassword: '$(My.Password)'
    jarsignerKeystoreAlias: 'certAlias'
    jarsignerKeyPassword: '$(My.Password)'
    jarsignerArguments: '-sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256'
    zipalign: true
```

Is there any way I can combine these into a single task?

I tried

```
apkfiles: "$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/*.(aab|apk)"
```

But ADO seems not to like that, says it cannot find files

Would this need a more formal fully qualifies regex to work?

Or does it just not work like that and I should stick with the two separate tasks?

Apprecaite any insight

Thanks